# dynamics crm contact fullname for custom entities

Tags: entity, crm, contacts, microsoft-dynamics

Im using dynamics CRM 2011.

I took a look at the entity called contact.

This entity has a fullname primary field that is automatically populated.
This field is not visible to the crm user when creating a new contact.

I was wondering how do I achieve the same with custom entities?

Do I use workflow to update the primary key field and hide the field from the crm users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be one (and the easiest) way to do it, stick a workflow on the create and update of the relevant fields - though users would have to wait a couple of minutes to see the change.

Other options could be a plugin if you want the field to be updated synchronously, or you could use JavaScript to show the field before the record is saved.

You could use the a AutoNumber Plugin here, there is one on CodePlex (I havent used it myself): http://crm2011autonumber.codeplex.com/